# Emacs custom command line argument

Tags: emacs, elisp

From the documentation I can see I can access command line arguments (command-line-args).
I'd like to add my own arguments but Emacs complains at start up that it doesn't recognize them.

E.g.

```
emacs -my_argument
```

I get:

```
command-line-1: Unknown option `-my_argument'
```

What's a proper way to define my custom arguments and provide information to my Emacs session?
Is there a way to pop an argument from a command line?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add something like this to your `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el`, or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
(defun my-argument-fn (switch)
  (message "i was passed -my_argument"))

(add-to-list 'command-switch-alist '("-my_argument" . my-argument-fn))
```

Then you can execute `emacs -my_argument` and it should print `i was passed -my_argument` to the minibuffer.  You can find more information in the [GNU elisp reference](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html).

Answer (score 12):

As stated in another post you can add your custom switches to `command-switch-alist` and emacs will call the handler function for any matching switch passed in on the command line. However, this operation is done after your `.emacs` file has been evaluated. This is fine for most cases but you may wish for a command line argument to alter the execution path or behaviour of your `.emacs` evaluation; I often do this to enable/disable configuration chunks (mainly for debugging).

To achieve this you can read `command-line-args` and check for your switch manually and then delete it from the list, this will stop `emacs` complaining about an unknown argument.

```
(setq my-switch-found (member "-myswitch" command-line-args))
(setq command-line-args (delete "-myswitch" command-line-args))
```

Which can alter your `.emacs` evaluation like so:

```
(unless my-switch-found
  (message "Didn't find inhibit switch, loading some config.") 
  ...)
```

And you could build this into a single step:

```
;; This was written in SO text-box, not been tested.
(defun found-custom-arg (switch)
  (let ((found-switch (member switch command-line-args)))
    (setq command-line-args (delete switch command-line-args))
    found-switch))

(unless (found-custom-arg "-myswitch")
  (message "Loading config...")
  ...)
```

Comment: Tested the code marked "not been tested". It works exactly as described.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, here is a code snip to show how to process custom arguments in Emacs lisp. In this case, I am processing an argument `--suffix` / `-S` to variable `_suffix`.

I pulled the idea from a [BSD-Lite Script](https://github.com/zhuqiuzhi/4.4BSD-Lite/blob/d998997dff53cdb57ed0845c4e55239830fdf63e/4.4BSD-Lite2/usr/src/contrib/emacs-18.57/lisp/startup.el) Emacs script.

```lisp
  (setq _suffix nil)

  ;; Process cli args
  (while command-line-args-left 
    (setq k (car command-line-args-left))
    (setq command-line-args-left (cdr command-line-args-left))
    (setq command-line-args (delete k command-line-args))
    (cond
      (or (string-equal k "--cs-suffix")
          (string-equal k "-S"))
        (setq _suffix (intern (car command-line-args-left)))
        (setq command-line-args-left (cdr command-line-args-left))
        (setq command-line-args (delete _suffix command-line-args))
      )))
```

This will roll through `command-line-args-left` and remove them all from `command-line-args` which will prevent `Emacs` from complaining.