# Start emacs from shell with predefined lisp code

Tags: shell, emacs, lisp

It is possible to start emacs from the shell and tell it to execute a lisp function, e.g.

```
emacs -f some-lisp-function my_file.py
```

However, I would like to pass also lisp functions with arguments, like

```
emacs -f "(goto-line 10)" my_file.py
# --> not working
```

and in the best of all worlds, pass also more complex lisp code consisting of multiple function calls, like

```
emacs -f "(goto-line 10) (some-other-func some-arg)" my_file.py
# --> not working
```

Does somebody know how?

**Edit:** To clarify this point, I need a way to evaluate the lisp code in the file's own buffer, *after* opening it.

(Btw. I know that the goto-line problem could be solved differently without using `-f` but thats just one example for my general problem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `emacs my_file.py --eval '(progn (goto-line 10) (some-other-func some-arg))'`.  Also note that invoking Emacs as `emacs +10 my_file.py` will open the file at the tenth line.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it does not what I want, for example `emacs --eval '(progn (goto-line 10))' my_file.py` will not do what's expected. What I look for is a way to evaluate lisp code in the file's own buffer, *after* loading it.

Comment: I have just edited the command line ordering in my post to do exactly what you are asking for.  I just tested it and it works on Emacs 24.3.50.7

Answer (score 2):

You have access to the command line that Emacs was invoked with.  You can add code to handle your own command line switches.  Depending on what you want, this may be cleaner than `--eval`.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html and [Emacs custom command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112256/emacs-custom-command-line-argument).